# IRunbookManager HybridWorkerGroup.HybridRunbookWorkers count = 0 while I do have a Hybrid Worker

Tags: c#, blazor, azure-automation

Hopefully you can help me, because I'm out of ideas...

I have a Blazor app where I use the Runbookmanager interface to make a connection to my Azure Automation environment.
I want to show the HybridRunbookWorkers per HybridRunbookWorker**Group**.

unfortunately, somehow the HybridRunbookWorkers keep showing as 0 HWs even though I do have a HybridRunbookWorker in my HybridRunbookWorkerGroup.

I do not have that much experience with either c# or the runbookmanager so I'm hoping you can help me.

I'm using the following:

```
        Task<List<HybridRunbookWorker>>? GetHybridWorkers(string HybridWorkerName);

        public async Task<List<HybridRunbookWorker>>? GetHybridWorkers(string HybridWorkerName)
        {
            M8Auto.RefreshTokenIfExpired();
            //var   result = M8Auto.Client!.HybridRunbookWorkerGroups.Get(rg, account, HybridWorkerName);
            var result = await M8Auto.Client!.HybridRunbookWorkerGroups.GetAsync(rg, account, HybridWorkerName);
            var runbookWorkersList = result.HybridRunbookWorkerGroup.HybridRunbookWorkers.ToList();
            if (runbookWorkersList != null)
                return runbookWorkersList;
            else
                return null!;
        }
```

This will show a count of zero with a list that is empty.

I also tried this:

```
        Task<HybridRunbookWorkerGroupGetResponse>? GetHybridWorkerGroup(string HybridWorkerName);
        public async Task<HybridRunbookWorkerGroupGetResponse>? GetHybridWorkerGroup(string HybridWorkerName)
        {
            M8Auto.RefreshTokenIfExpired();
            //var   result = M8Auto.Client!.HybridRunbookWorkerGroups.Get(rg, account, HybridWorkerName);
            var result = await M8Auto.Client!.HybridRunbookWorkerGroups.GetAsync(rg, account, HybridWorkerName);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
            else
                return null!;
        }
        HybridWorkerGroupResponseData = await GetHybridWorkerGroup(HybridWorkerGroup);
                if (HybridWorkerGroupResponseData.HybridRunbookWorkerGroup.HybridRunbookWorkers.Count == 0)
                {
                    new Exception("A Hybrid Worker Group exist, but does not contain a Hybrid Worker.");
                }
```

This is what is shown in the Visual Studio debugger:
[image: Empty]